# Maven jar dependencies are displayed outside `Maven Dependencies` view

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, m2e

I recently started developing a Spring MVC maven project. After I run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command from the run configurations all the maven dependencies are displayed outside the project and not under "Maven Dependencies" Hierarchy view. When I switch my project perspective to Java from Java EE then the dependencies are found under `Referenced Libararies`.

[image: Screenshot]

My [.project](http://pastebin.com/ML4g0bDw) and [.classpath](http://pastebin.com/pC2GtCtD) metadata file contents.

Anybody got idea on how to display all the jars under the `Maven Dependencies` view?

Comment: Yes. Don't use the eclipse plugin from maven. Use the maven plugin from eclipse. Means: Do not run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on any project, but import your project as a maven project in eclipse and let the M2E plugin do its job.

Comment: The core of any maven project is the `src` directory and the `pom.xml`. Nothing else. Eclipse creates the metadata files and directories (`.project`, `.classpath`, `.settings/`) itself when importing. So you could delete them first. By the way: The eclipse plugin from maven also creates them, but they then don't always fit.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thanks for your inputs. Will delete the directories now and try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I thought, giving an answer might be better than writing comments.

**The Maven Eclipse plugin**

Assume you have the following project directory:

```
/hello-world/
   +-- src/
   +-- pom.xml
```

You now run a `mvn eclipse:eclipse` inside that directory to *eclipsify* it. This will create some meta files:

```
/hello-world/
   +-- src/
   +-- pom.xml
   +-- .project
   +-- .classpath
```

The `.project` file will contain a comment line with the statement

> NO_M2ECLIPSE_SUPPORT: Project files created with the maven-eclipse-plugin are not supported in M2Eclipse.

The `.classpath` will have entries for the dependencies like these:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3-sources.jar"/>
```

Note that these entries are using an eclipse internal variable: `M2_REPO`, which points to your local maven repository. After all these entries are simple library entries. The same that you would get when adding a library to the build path.

If you now import this via "Existing Projects into Workspace", you will exactly get the project that you described. Libraries are simple *classpath entries*. And - more important - it doesn't have the maven nature (it is missing the little "M" icon). That was mentioned in the `.project` file. Without the maven nature you do not have some useful and important features for this project.

**The Eclipse Maven plugin**

So, let's repair that. Make a backup of the project directory first (in case of anything going wrong).

First step is to remove the project from eclipse, but not from the harddisk. So simply delete it in eclipse, but don't tick "Delete project contents on disk". You still want to have this project, don't you?

Step 2: Navigate to the project directory and delete any eclipse meta files (I already told you). Afterwards you have the same project directory as in the initial situation.

Step 3: Now you can import this project into eclipse with "Existing Maven Projects". Browse to the directory that contains your project (might be the workspace directory) and select your project.

You will notice afterwards that this project now has the maven nature. There is a little "M" icon at the project icon. Additionally, you will see all libraries under a "Maven Dependencies" node.

Why is that so? Let's have a look at the meta files again:

The `.project` file now also contains the following lines (among others):

```
<buildCommand><name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name></buildCommand>
<nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
```

The `.classpath` now also has the following entry:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

And the M2E plugin now is doing the rest. Easy, isn't it?

Comment: wow Great!! Thanks that solved it. but I din't have any .classpath file in my project root directory. I could only find `.project` file and `.settings` directory. However I deleted them as you suggested and imported the project as Existing Maven projects. But after importing as Existing Maven project the `.classpath` file is created. See my pastebin link of those file contents in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

@Lucky close eclipse. do an eclipse:clean from command prompt and import the project as Maven project..(assuming you have maven plugin installed in eclipse).I think this would show it the desired way.

Comment: The only caveat here:  `eclise:clean` deletes the .project, .classpath files, so if OP has done any customization that will be deleted using this method.  Otherwise, this is probably the fastest way to recover.